# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor is not downloading all data

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, threadpoolexecutor

I am using python `threadpoolexecutor` to download PDFs, but it is missing some data. It is not downloading all files.

The snippet of my code is:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(download, names)
```

Here download is the function for downloading the data and names is the list of all URL's and I am using `requests` module to make request.

```
def download(name):
    r = requests.get(URL + name, timeout = 15)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        print(name)
```

Comment: your if statement is most likely false if it's missing data

Comment: @Kenan that's not an issue I tested it without using multi-threading it was getting everything then

Comment: hmm....have you tried multiprocessing and got the same issue?

Comment: No i haven't tried multiprocessing